# Is there a way to make a bash variable "return" a different value each time I use it?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program that requires the serial number of a USB device. Each time I connect a different device, need to run a couple of shell commands to get its serial number and use that as an argument to my program. It is exhausting.

Is there a way to assign a "dynamic" value to a variable so I can use it like:

./myprog $USB_SERIAL

Comment: We have something that works like "reverse": a script that does some initial setup, and that then provides a bash function `r()` ... and then you do `r some-tool` ... and the r function will do all the required computing and invoke the tool as we need it, with the information required to run it.

Comment: so something like `$RANDOM`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not writing a shell script which will execute the couple of commands for you?

Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

command1
command2
command3
serial=...

echo "$serial"
```

Then you just have to put the command in a `$PATH` directory, something like `/usr/local/bin/get_serial`, and you can use it like this:

```
./myprog "$(get_serial)"
```

Don't forget to my make your script executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/get_serial
```

Comment: Well, a shell script is the "obvious" way to go. I was wondering if there was a different way.